# Object is deallocated - why? where?

Tags: iphone, nsstring, memory-management

Ok, I spent the last 8 hours fighting with it - it just seems beyond me.  Here's my complete (relevant) code:

```
- (void)updateUserDefaults
{
    NSMutableDictionary *viewControllerDetails = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:4];

    [viewControllerDetails setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:OOVenueClassControllerType] forKey:@"classType"];
    [viewControllerDetails setObject:self.searchTerm forKey:@"searchTerm"];
    [viewControllerDetails setObject:self.searchLocation forKey:@"searchLocation"];

    //----- the next two lines cause the problem
    NSString *res = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[searchResults xmlString]] retain];
    [viewControllerDetails setObject:res forKey:@"searchresults"];
    //-----

    NSMutableArray *viewControllersList = [NSMutableArray array] ;
    [viewControllersList addObject:viewControllerDetails];

    NSUserDefaults *defs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    //the following line causes the error
    [defs setObject:viewControllersList forKey:kViewControllersKey];
    [defs synchronize];

    [res release];
}
```

Note the block with `the next two lines cause the problem`.  At first I didn't create another string, but added it later while trying to solve the problem.

If I comment out those two lines, everything works fine.  If I put them back in, I get

```
- [CFString class]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xa1a9000
```

Is something is wrong with the string that I'm trying to put into the userdefaults?  That string is rather large (about 200,000 characters), but I had stored even longer strings in user defaults in the past.

It's also worth noting that if I uninstall the app, then everything works fine.  But on subsequent runs the problem exhibits itself.

So, how and why and where is the string getting deallocated?  I have explicitly added `retain` - but that still doesn't help.  What am I missing?

**Edit:** just realised I forgot to say that the error is thrown on line

```
[defs setObject:viewControllersList forKey:kViewControllersKey];
```

Also, for general information, method `- (NSString *)xmlString` on `searchResults` does exactly what the name means: creates an XML string with the information from that object.

**Edit 2:** I tried doing something else with that string - convert it to `NSData`, compress using zlib - but regardless of data type, that particular object gets deallocated.  Does it have to do something with the size of the string?

Comment: I suspect that it's `[searchResults xmlString]` that's the problem, but that doesn't appear anywhere in your code. Could you show us other code that uses it?

Comment: @Louis: I updated the question with some additional information

Comment: How is `kViewControllersKey` defined?

Comment: Why are you retaining `res`? It's an autoreleased `NSString`, but it seems highly unlikely you are draining the autorelease pool between those 2 lines of code. After you create `res` have verified it has the correct data (either NSLog or debug inspection)? Is this method being run on the main thread? If not, how is it being called?

Comment: @DBD Yes, I verified it - and it contains the correct data once created.  And, yes, it's running on the main thread.

Comment: @Joe `kViewcontrollersKey` is defined as `#define kViewControllersKey   @"ControllersList"`

Comment: Pretty much the second thing I always do in such cases (the first is to pound my head against the wall a few times) is to run the analyzer.  It catches probably 90% of the dumb mistakes you make in storage management.

Comment: Does problem occur if you replace `[searchResults xmlString]` with some string constant?

Comment: @tia: tried that - no error, so something is related to that string/object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, not sure what exactly the problem was, but it was somewhere in the `searchResults` and/or `xmlString` method.  `searchResults` object is originally created from XML received from the server (XML is parsed into the object structure).  When `xmlString` was called, for some reason the string I was getting back was different from the original XML (I'm not talking about formatting, of course) - of 200,000 char-long string, within the first 500 chars or so there were some differences. I haven't been able to figure out why. So, instead of recreating the xml from object structure, I instead stored the original XML in a field in that object and, when `xmlString` was called, simply returned the original string.  Now everything worked fine.

Thank you all for your support through this painful process.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *res = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[searchResults xmlString]] retain];
```

Is auto released.  You don't need to release it at the end of your method.  You are over-releasing it.

Further, you don't need to retain the `[searchResults xmlString]`.  The `stringWithFormat` method already does it for you.

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks for your comment, however it's definitely not the problem, because execution never gets to that line.  The error is thrown on line `[defs setObject:viewControllersList forKey:kViewControllersKey];
`

Comment: `res` got retained and released afterward so it is not over-releasing, it's just unnecessary in this case.